# rJava: REngine or Rengine, what is the difference?

Tags: rjava, jri

I notice that there are two classes you can use in JAva to talk with R:

REngine, 
Rengine

Despite each has different ways of creating an instance and different methods to evaluate an R expression, what are the key differences? Which one should I use?

Thanks